# jQuery custom validation displays only error of last field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've written the following simple validation code with Jquery, everything is working fine but only the error of last field is displayed.
I've started placing this fieldset with an error div:

```
<fieldset data-check-id="1">
<div class="fs-error"></div>
<input type="text" size="50" id="ptitle" name="title" />
<input type="text" id="address" name="p_address">
</fieldset>
```

Next I've tried something like this

```
function check($fs){
var ok = true;
switch($fs.attr('data-check-id')){
case '1':

$ptitle = $('#ptitle',$fs);
$address = $('#address',$fs);

//title
if ($ptitle.val().length == 0) {
ok=false;
jQuery( "#ptitle" ).css( "border-bottom", "2px solid red" );
jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Error 1 </span>');
jQuery('.fs-error').show();
}
else{
jQuery( "#ptitle" ).css( "border-bottom", "2px solid rgb(0, 102, 0)" );
jQuery('.fs-error').hide();
}

//Address
if ($address.val().length == 0) {
ok=false;
jQuery( "#address" ).css( "border-bottom", "2px solid red" );
jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Error 2 </span>');
jQuery('.fs-error').show();
}
else{
jQuery( "#address" ).css( "border-bottom", "2px solid rgb(0, 102, 0)" );
jQuery('.fs-error').hide();
}
break;
}

if(ok === true){
        $fs.attr('data-complete', true);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        $fs.attr('data-complete', false);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Function for checking

```
function form_completeCheck(){
  var ok = true;
  $('fieldset').each(function(index,elem){
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('data-complete') != 'true') {
      ok = false;
    };
  })

  if (ok === true) {
    //go go go..
    return true;
  }
  else{
    // stop
    return false;
  }

}
```

Now everything is working correctly but if both title and address are not filled it shows only the address error (**Error 2**). If I insert the address, title input is highlighted with red border but its message is not displayed (**Error 1**). What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: _"it shows only the address error (Error 2)"_ Appear to be overwriting exisiting `html` at `jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Error 2 </span>');` ? You could alternatively utilize `html5`, `css` to achieve requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are 2 errors only second one is showing because you're completely rewriting fs-error div with this line (erasing what was there before):

```
jQuery('.fs-error').html('<span style="color:red;"> Error 2 </span>');
```

In your second case Error 1 is not displayed because you're hiding div in your second Address validation:

```
jQuery('.fs-error').hide();
```

You want to hide it only if there are no errors.

Comment: Thanks for your great help! @Walk

Comment: @XiLab no problem, here's a quick fix that should work http://pastebin.com/JM4NGhqf (commented lines and changed second "html()" to "append()").

Answer (score 1):

An approach utilizing `HTML5` `required`, `pattern` attributes; `CSS` `counter`, `:invalid` , `:valid`, `:not()`, `::after` , `content`, general sibling selector `~`

```css
body {
  counter-reset: err;
  counter-reset: err2;
  counter-increment: err2 2;
}
.fs-error {
  display: none;
}
input:not(:invalid) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 102, 0);
}
input:invalid {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
input:invalid ~ .fs-error {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  color: red;
}
input:nth-of-type(1):invalid ~ input:valid ~ .fs-error::after {
  counter-increment: err;
  content: "Error " counter(err);
}
input:nth-of-type(1):valid ~ input:nth-of-type(2):invalid ~ .fs-error::after {
  counter-increment: err 2;
  content: "Error " counter(err);
}
input:nth-of-type(1):invalid ~ input:nth-of-type(2):invalid ~ .fs-error::after {
  counter-increment: err;
  content: "Error " counter(err)", Error " counter(err2);
}
```

```html
<fieldset data-check-id="1">
  <br>1
  <input type="text" size="50" id="ptitle" name="title" minlength="1" pattern="\w+" required/>
  <br>2
  <input type="text" id="address" name="p_address" minlength="1" pattern="\w+" required/>
  <div class="fs-error"><span></span>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```