# changing the properties in a external CSS thorugh Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's an external CSS file and I want to change one of the property of a class using JS. The property "content" in this class should dynamically change with a local directory of images.

```
    .carousel-cell {
     width: 75%;
     height: 580px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     background: #8C8;
     border-radius: 5px;
     counter-increment: gallery-cell;
    }
   /* cell number */
   .carousel-cell:before {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    content: counter(gallery-cell);
    line-height: 580px;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: white;
   }
```

What changes should be done in order to take in list of images in a local folder using JS. The 'images' folder contains 8-10 images.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What exactly would you like to be in the `content` property? Show us your desired result. Remember that `content` only takes certain kinds of value. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: What do you mean by _"dynamically change with a local directory of images"_? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678446/jquery-custom-validation-displays-only-error-of-last-field/

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Using the url() method like : `content: url(http://www.example.com/test.png);`

Comment: Okay, so do you want to rewrite the file itself? Or just override it at run-time?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat override at run-time

Comment: Ah, you could just appendChild a style tag with the styles inside, maybe?